# SpringBoot Java project - mvn site - [WARNING] Unable to find a URL to the parent project. The parent menu will NOT be added

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Small question on a SpingBoot + Java + Maven project.

Issue can be reproduced 100% of the time.

I have a pom file as follow (java code is not needed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <name>someName</name>
    <description> some description</description>
    <url>https://pages.github.com</url>
    <organization>
        <name>myOrg</name>
    </organization>
    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com</url>
    </scm>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cvequestion</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-micrometer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
            <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart-for-netty</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <reportsDirectory>target/reports/junit</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/javadoc</outputDirectory>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>target/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/findbugs</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.16.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetDirectory>.out/reports/pmd</targetDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/pmd</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>.out/reports/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/checkstyle</outputDirectory>
                    <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>10.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>json</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <withHistory>true</withHistory>
                    <threads>16</threads>
                    <outputFormats>
                        <param>XML</param>
                        <param>HTML</param>
                    </outputFormats>
                    <mutators>
                        <mutator>CONDITIONALS_BOUNDARY</mutator>
                        <mutator>INCREMENTS</mutator>
                        <mutator>INVERT_NEGS</mutator>
                        <mutator>MATH</mutator>
                        <mutator>NEGATE_CONDITIONALS</mutator>
                        <mutator>EMPTY_RETURNS</mutator>
                        <mutator>FALSE_RETURNS</mutator>
                        <mutator>TRUE_RETURNS</mutator>
                        <mutator>PRIMITIVE_RETURNS</mutator>
                        <mutator>REMOVE_INCREMENTS</mutator>
                        <mutator>EXPERIMENTAL_BIG_INTEGER</mutator>
                        <mutator>EXPERIMENTAL_MEMBER_VARIABLE</mutator>
                        <mutator>EXPERIMENTAL_SWITCH</mutator>
                    </mutators>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.15</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

When executing this command `mvnw clean install site dependency:tree -X` , 100% of the time, I can see:

```
[INFO] Rendering site with default locale English (en)
[DEBUG] Computing decoration model of org.example:cvequestion:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT for locale en
[DEBUG] No site descriptor.
[DEBUG] Looking for site descriptor of level 1 parent project: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.6
[DEBUG] No site descriptor found for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.6 for locale en, trying without locale...
[DEBUG] No site descriptor found for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.6 without locale.
[DEBUG] No parent level 1 site descriptor.
[DEBUG] Looking for site descriptor of level 2 parent project: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.6.6
[DEBUG] No site descriptor found for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.6.6 for locale en, trying without locale...
[DEBUG] No site descriptor found for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.6.6 without locale.
[DEBUG] No parent level 2 site descriptor.
[DEBUG] Site decoration model inheritance: assembling child with level 2 parent: distributionManagement.site.url child = null and parent = null
[DEBUG] Site decoration model inheritance: assembling child with level 1 parent: distributionManagement.site.url child = null and parent = null
[DEBUG] Using default site descriptor
[WARNING] Unable to find a URL to the parent project. The parent menu will NOT be added.
```

May I ask what is the meaning of "site descriptor" and "parent" please?

May I ask how do I fix this please?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that there are parent POM or other dependent packages you need in the private server. If not, please do not execute clean first, execute the install command to publish the package to the private server, and then carry out other packaging operations. Lesson of blood